# lighttpd: Does it still have memory leak and CPU consumption issues?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, lighttpd

This page here compares nginx and lighttpd:

http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Lighttpd_vs_nginx

There are numerous reports of memory leaks unfixed for years as well as severely worse CPU consumption (2% with nginx compared to 98% with lighttpd).

Do these problems still exist in the current stable version? (apparently 1.4.28 from the official website)

Answer (score 5):

There is a recent [side-by-side comparison of the nginx/1.0.6 and lighttpd/1.4.29 resource consumption](http://forum.gwan.com/index.php?p=/discussion/525/nginx1.0.6-vs-lighttpd1.4.29-vs-g-wan2.9.30-rpscpuram/) and they both look good, albeit with different profiles (performances/resources):

The rather long tests do not show memory leaks (many charts included).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on comparing it with nginx, but I've used lighttpd for years serving static content with no issues. It is entirely possible the memory leaks are only evident with dynamic pages (e.g. PHP) or with a certain module (I run only a handful of basic modules).

Comment: In other words, you don't know...